# maximum RAM capacity DX58SO + i7 920 only 8Gb

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, bios, intel-core-i7

I have a i7 920 cpu on a DX58SO motherboard.

Reading the specs of these, I concluded that the maximum RAM capacity should be 16 Gb.
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37147/intel-core-i7-920-processor-8m-cache-2-66-ghz-4-80-gt-s-intel-qpi.html
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005844/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html

However, dmidecode on Linux reports that the maximum capacity is 8 Gb.

Does someone have a hint about where this difference may come from? Maybe the BIOS should be updated? Thanks in advance.

Below some output from dmidecode:

```
# dmidecode 3.1
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: J1PR
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i7
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 26, Stepping 5
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         920  @ 2.67GHz

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Intel Corp.
    Version: SOX5810J.86A.4598.2009.1211.1321
    Release Date: 12/11/2009
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 2048 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
    BIOS Revision: 0.0
    Firmware Revision: 0.0

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 2, 20 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
    Product Name: DX58SO
    Version: AAE29331-702
    Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Base Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x0008
    Type: Unknown
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0014
    Partition Width: 4

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J1MY
    Bank Locator: CHAN A DIMM 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0x0198

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J2MY
    Bank Locator: CHAN A DIMM 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0x0198

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J3MY
    Bank Locator: CHAN B DIMM 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J4MY
    Bank Locator: CHAN C DIMM 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0xFEFF, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: According to your second link, Single sided ram is limited to 8gb, Dual sided ram is 16gb max.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But why does Linux assume that I am going to use single-sided RAM in the remaining empty slots? The two slots I am using now are 1Rx16 https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr13n9s6_2.pdf memories, but in the two remaining ones, I could maybe use double-sided versions?

Comment: Maybe because it has single sided installed?

Comment: But I thought it was ok to mix single sided with double sided, so why does the BIOS assume that all would be of the same type? (dmidecode only reads what's encoded in the BIOS).